# Как сделать, чтобы рандомное число в поле num генерировалось через определенное время?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var i = getRandomInt(10, 50);
var e= +i;
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('num').value = e;
}
</script>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://my1.ru/main.php" name="r2" target="h2">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="check"> 
<input type="number" id="num" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в свой код setInterval

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
window.onload = function () {
    // берем элемент
    var element = document.getElementById('num');
    // делаем начальное значение
    element.value = getRandomInt(10, 50);
    // берем случайное число раз в секунду
    setInterval(function() {
        element.value = getRandomInt(10, 50);
    }, 1000)
}
</script>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://my1.ru/main.php" name="r2" target="h2">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="check"> 
<input type="number" id="num" value="">
</form>
```